# Inserir ao fim de lista- eficiente

Tags: c, lista

```
typedef struct NODO{
    int custo;
    int linha;
    int coluna;
    struct NODO *nseg[2];
}Nodo;

 Nodo * insertLastEfi(Nodo *L,Nodo *nv){
    Nodo * aux =L;
    if (L==NULL) {
        return nv;
    }
    while (L->nseg[1]!=NULL) {
        L=L->nseg[1];
    }
    L->nseg[1]=nv->nseg[1];
    L->nseg[0]=nv->nseg[0];
    return aux;
}
```

Implementei a seguinte função referida acima. O que eu quero fazer é:

para inserir um novo elemento na lista e em vez de passar por todos os elementos, introduzi um novo ponteiro para apontar logo para o ultimo elemento e de seguida adicionar o novo elemento. O programa corre bem mas quando peço no main:

```
Lista_r=insertLastEfi(Nodo *L,Nodo *nv)

printf("%d\n",Lista_r->custo);
```

devolve segmentation fault.

A função insertLastEfi é chamada 100 vezes para copiar 100 valores para os nós da lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fica difícil saber exatamente se existe algum outro problema com uma fração do código. Sempre forneça o código da forma mais completa possível já que sem ele não poderemos testar. Forneça os arquivos de entrada e tudo relevante. Devo dizer ainda que o erro pode estar em outra área que não aches estar.

Dito isto, aparentemente, a primeira seção de código está correta. A segunda está errada:você aparenta ter copiado a declaração da função e esquecido de colocar os valores corretos. Tente trocar

```
Lista_r=insertLastEfi(Nodo *L,Nodo *nv)
```

Por

```
Lista_r = insertLastEfi( Lista_r, nv );
```

Ou equivalente - troque as variáveis necessárias. Com isso, supondo que não haja mais erros em outros pontos não informados, o problema deve ser solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser que na condicao

```
if (L==NULL){
    return nv;
}
```

Quando entra nela, o retorno que no caso **nv** esteja nulo ou com lixo. Ai entra em partes da memoria que nao poderia entrar e da erro. Pois:

> Falha de segmentação (segmentation fault, também referido por
>   segfault) é um erro que ocorre em programa quando este tenta acessar
>   (para leitura ou escrita) um endereço na memória RAM que está
>   reservado para outro programa (ou o próprio sistema operativo) ou que
>   não existe.

Tambem veja se no primeiro ponteiro voce passa tudo certinho, ou seja, passa duas referencias.

So mais uma dica tente usar variaveis mais decritivas